# Faster methods of unzipping Assets

Tags: android, zip

I'm writting an app that deals with Zip files of content. I have a few different unzipping methods, depending on where the content is stored.
When unzipping on the SD card, I'm using ZipFile, and that's working great, as I'm always trying to get a specific file out of the zip.
When I'm dealling with a zip that is stored in Assets, I'm resorting to getting an InputStream from the asset, and then iterating through the stream to find the specific file that I'm looking for. e.g:

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream); // Editted following comment from Jave
ZipEntry entry;
ZipEntry targetEntry = null;
try {
    while (targetEntry == null
        && (entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        if (entry.getName().endsWith(fileName)) 
        {
            targetEntry = entry;
        }
    }
```

I'm finding that this iteration is taking way too much time. Does anyone know of a faster method to unzip an asset? (for example is there an alternate way to grab an asset, rather than getting it as a Stream?)
I can't really think of anything (other than perhaps copying the zip to the SD before I begin).

Comment: Try wrapping the inputStream in a `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jave. I've given this a try, but it doesn't seem to have had much of an affect. I'll leave this in anyway though (as I'm pretty sure I should have been doing that anyway)

Comment: Since the APK is a ZIP file itself, is there a reason why you are putting ZIPs in assets? There are reasons to do this (e.g., file size > 1MB), but otherwise, it's not like it's saving you any space.

Comment: @CommonsWare - The main reason for zipping them is more for accountability than saving space. The files are zipped by customers and then sent through to us. This means there is far less files sent to us that we have to account for/provide checksums for etc.

Comment: OK, but then please understand that your performance issues are self-inflicted. Particularly in mobile development, never do something at runtime that you could do, at least in part, at compile time. For example, you could put your customer's ZIP file somewhere else in your project tree (e.g., add a `customer/` directory), and augment your Ant build script to unzip that into `assets/customer/` when it changes. While this may not completely cover the benefits that you get with keeping it ZIP'd, it also eliminates the overhead of iterating over the contents of a ZIP file inside a ZIP (APK) file.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZipInputStream inZip = new ZipInputStream(MainActivity.this.getAssets().open(_zipFile));
```

Like this,your can get a zipFile by name from assets.